# Count the similarly degree between two names based on characters?

Tags: r, compare

are there any way to evaluate the similarity between the two names? As data is like below:

```
ABC  ABCD

CBD  CBD 

ABC  DEF
```

the result may be like

```
ABC  ABCD   (3/4=) 75%

CBD  CBD    (3/3=) 100%

ABC  DEF    (0/6=) 0%
```

also, the order of the character doesn't matter

Comment: What would be the expected result for "ABCCC" and "ABCD"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `length` of `intersect`s divided by `max`imum `nchar`, `apply`ed row-wise. We may optionally want to handle *dupes*.

```
#      V1    V2
# 1   ABC  ABCD
# 2   CBD   CBD
# 3   ABC   DEF
# 4 ABCCC  ABCC
# 5 ABCCC ABCCC
# 6 ABCCC  ABCD

f <- function(x, dupes=FALSE) {
  if (dupes) {
    x <- sapply(x, function(x) Reduce(paste0, unique(el(strsplit(x, "")))))
  }
  i <- length(do.call(intersect, unname(mapply(strsplit, x, ""))))
  m <- max(sapply(x, nchar))
  i/m
}

apply(d, 1, f)
# [1] 0.75 1.00 0.00 0.60 0.60 0.60
apply(d, 1, f, dupes=TRUE)
# [1] 0.75 1.00 0.00 1.00 1.00 0.75
```

---

*Data:*

```
d <- structure(list(V1 = c("ABC", "CBD", "ABC", "ABCCC", "ABCCC", 
"ABCCC"), V2 = c("ABCD", "CBD", "DEF", "ABCC", "ABCCC", "ABCD"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this code would provide the expected outputs.

```
fun_str_sml <- function(str1, str2){
  letters_list <- c(str1, str2) %>% map(~ str_split(., "")[[1]]) %>% reduce(c)
  return(letters_list %>% duplicated() %>% sum() / letters_list %>% unique() %>% length())
}
fun_str_sml("ABC", "ABCD") # => 0.75
fun_str_sml("ABC", "CDEF") # => 0.1666667 (1/6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using set operations with `mapply` :

```
mapply(function(x, y) length(intersect(x, y))/length(union(x, y)), 
       strsplit(df$V1, ''), strsplit(df$V2, '')) * 100

#[1]  75 100   0
```

Comment: With this solution also e.g. CBD-CDB  would be 100% similar.

Comment: Yes as per my understanding that is what is expected because OP mentions `the order of the character doesn't matter`